# JQuery - Browse elements from a main div

Tags: jquery, element

i've a list of div linked to a main div-root. How can browse all elements of the main div? example :

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="trackon" id="trackline1">Line 1</div>
    <div class="trackon" id="trackline2">Line 2</div>
    <div class="trackon" id="trackline3">Line 3</div>
    <div class="trackoff" id="trackline4">Line 4</div>
    <div class="trackoff" id="trackline5">Line 5</div>
</div>
```

i'm looking for a jquery function that browse all elements (like a for each statament) of #main div. I've tried to search on official documentation but i find nothing! cheers

Comment: Well, you got 5 of effectively the same answer, but no one gave a link to the docs you couldn't find, so here you go. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#main div').each(function(){
//$(this) is the current div
});
```

Or, if you want to make sure you just grab first level divs,

```
$('#main > div').each(function(){
//$(this) is the current div
});
```

Comment: yeah! in fact i miss to specific a thing : and if i want to select only children div which have a specific class? in that example all child with "trackon" class. I use .find() ?

Comment: To get elements of just one class, you can use: `$('#main>div.trackon')`.  This will get all divs (with a class of 'trackon') that are children of main.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#main>div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#main').children().each(function(){
    alert($(this));
});
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Also when its not a div, like a table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each` like this:

```
$('$main > div').each(function(){
  // your code...
});
```

The `>` is child selector which is used here to select direct/immediate children of parent div.